# Get Object Type from Array of Keys

Tags: typescript

I have a set of storage properties:

```
interface StoredProps {
  location: boolean;
  notification: boolean;
}
```

I also get the strings representing the stored properties using `keyof`:

```
type StorableKeys = keyof StoredProps;
```

I have a function that can retrieve multiple stored properties at once:

```
const = getStoredProps<T extends StorableKeys[]>(keys: T) =>
  keys.map(key => storage.get(key)).reduce((props, value, idx) => {
    props[keys[idx]] = value;
    return props;
  }, {});
```

This works, however the return type is ultimately `{}`. I want the return type to match an object created by the keys.

I've tried using `{} as { [M in keyof T]: T[M] }`, but this doesn't work because `T` is an array type so this just ends up giving me an array type. I've also tried `[M in T]`, but this is a syntax error.

Is there any way to derive a type from an array of property names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
const getStoredProps = <K extends StorableKeys>(keys: K[]) =>
  keys.map(key => storage.get(key)).reduce((props, value, idx) => {
    props[keys[idx]] = value;
    return props;
  }, {} as Pick<StoredProps, K>);
}
```

The idea is to make the generic type just a union of keys `K` instead of an array of them, which is more straightforward.  And then `keys` is of type `K[]`.  The real value is the return type, `Pick<StoredProps, K>`, which is defined like `{[P in K]: StoredProps[P]}`, and it works now because `K` is a key type not an array type.

You might have been able to get away with `T extends StorableKeys[]` and then `Pick<StoredProps, T[number]>`, but I don't think you really mean to say that `T` could be a subtype of `Array`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.